# D3: Nested elements are not visible but in Dom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to append a nested selection in d3 (lines in rects). The DOM elements are visible in the inspector, but do not appear in the visualization. My code looks something like this:

```
var rects = itemRects.selectAll("rect")
    .data(scope.items)
    .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.timeline.processStarts);})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.timeline.processEnds) - x1(d.timeline.processStarts);});

var rectsContent = rects.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "item")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.cycleColor; })
    .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.timeOne);})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + .1 * y1(1) + 0.5;})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.timeTwo) - x1(d.timeline.processStarts);})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

rects.exit().remove();
```

And now I want to append the nested lines in my rects:

```
var strokes = rectsContent.append("g").selectAll("line")
    .data(function(d) { return d.timestamps; })
    //.attr("d", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return x1(d3.values(d)[0]);})
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return x1(d3.values(d)[0]);});

strokes
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class","line")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d3.values(d)[0]); return x1(d3.values(d)[0]);}) // I get the right data!
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return x1(d3.values(d)[0]);})
    .attr("y1", function(d, i, j) { return y1(scope.items[j].lane); })
    .attr("y2", function(d, i, j) { return y1(scope.items[j].lane) + mainLaneHeight; });

strokes.exit().remove();
```

As I said the lines are visible in the DOM inspector, but not in the application. When I **don't** nest the data and use the lines parallel to the rects it works (but I can only show the first element, because there is no nesting):

```
var strokes = itemRects.append("g").selectAll("line")
    .data(scope.items[0].timestamps)
    //.attr("d", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return x1(d3.values(d)[0]);})
    ....
```

What could be wrong with the nesting? Is it because I do enter() on the rects and have to wait until I can append the children lines?

EDIT:

When I try to append my rects to a group element, the rects do not appear. In the DOM inspector they do not appear too.

```
var g = itemRects.selectAll("g")
    .data(scope.items).enter().append("g");

var rects = g.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x", function(d) {return x1(d.start);})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.end) - x1(d.start);});

var rectsContent = rects.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "item")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .attr("x", function(d) {return console.log(d); x1(d.start);}) // does not get triggered
    .attr("y", function(d) {return y1(d.lane) + .1 * y1(1) + 0.5;})
    .attr("width", function(d) {return x1(d.end) - x1(d.start);})
    .attr("height", function(d) {return .8 * y1(1);});

rects.exit().remove();
```

Comment: In SVG, any elements in `rect`s won't be displayed. Use `g` elements to group the `rect` and `line` elements together. That is, have a `g` element with the `rect` and `line`s underneath.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. But when I try this my rects won't be appended to my groups. My groups are visible in the DOM inspector, but not the rects. See my edit in my question.

Comment: You're doing a nested selection there where there's no nested data. Simply `g.append("rect").attr(...)` should be enough. You don't need to handle any selections for `rects` (or indeed have them) because there's a 1-1 correspondence between `g`s and `rect`s, so all of that should be done on the `g` elements.

Comment: Got it. But then how do I update all the groups? Just                 var g = itemRects.selectAll("g").data(scope.items).enter().append("g"); with the new data?

Comment: Yes, although I would save the selection: `var g = itemRects.selectAll("g").data(scope.items); g.enter().append("g"); g.exit().remove()`